# Trouble connecting iOS App with AWS EC2 server

Tags: swift, xcode, https

I am testing registration codes for an iOS app to a server hosted on AWS EC2 (tomcat, apache). I keep getting errors, like these:

> TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x283bc6280]: 3:0
>
> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>
> Task <2F787366-D258-488D-AD2C-2FE696D08BF2>.<1> HTTP load failed
>   (error code: -1202 [3:-9813]).

I searched and changed the **info.plist** according to several suggestions:

```
// Here are my sample codes
// Send HTTP Request to Register user
let myUrl = URL(string: "https://ec2xxx.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/MyAPISever/api.json")
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

let postString = "username=\(userName)&password=\(userPassword)&first_name=\(firstName)&last_name=\(lastName)&email=\(userEmail)"

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

 // parse response....

 task.resume()
```

Still the problem persists. I am using Swift 4.0 and Xcode 10.2. Here is my info.plist additions:

```
Allow Arbitary Loads

Exception Domains : amazonaws.com

IncludeSubdomains : true

NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : true

NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy : false

NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion : TLSv1.2

NSRequiresCertificateTransparency : false
```

Comment: Did you forget to set up a security group on AWS console?

Comment: yes. but will double check.